# Can we enable ASLR, DEP, SafeSEH, Authenticode, Control Flow Guard, and HighEntropyVA to an exe file from VB 6.0 ?? (I am new to VB6)

Tags: security, linker, vb6, aslr, dep

I am new to Microsoft Visual Basic. I need to enable ASLR, DEP, SafeSEH, Authenticode, Control Flow Guard, and HighEntropyVA. Can anyone guide me in the right direction? Everywhere it is given for C++ but not for VB6. we cannot use any third-party tool to enable. We can either configure in VB IDE or use Powershell scripts.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `LINK.EXE` used by VB6 is version 6.0 (from Visual Studio 6.0) and all of these switches are not supported (yet). You might be able to use newer version of `LINK.EXE` and use `LinkSwitches` option in `.vbp` project file to manually pass the flags.